# What is the proper way of adding a license header into a .vue file?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I need to add a license header into all .vue files in the project. What is the proper placement for it and what tags should be used?

Should it be with `<!--  -->`  tags  or  `/*   */`  ?
Should it be in the beginning of the file or inside the script part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Vue SFC Specification](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html) states that `.vue` files use HTML-like syntax, and top-level comments must have the HTML comment syntax too (`<!-- -->`).

> A `*.vue` file is a custom file format that uses HTML-like syntax to describe a Vue component.
>
> [...]
>
> For top-level comments, use HTML comment syntax: `<!-- comment contents here -->`

I think license *headers* meant to be inserted at the beginning of the file so developers can see it early after opening it, so I would place it there.

(Though I would suggest to rethink [whether you really need to do this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125836/do-you-have-to-include-a-license-notice-with-every-source-file).)